# R dplyr/tidyr recode column values

Tags: r, dplyr, tidyr, recode, key-pair

I had multiple data sets that I merged into 1 dplyr dataframe with rbind.

```
GapAnalysis16 <- select(memSat16,
     importance_communication_website_content, 
     satisfaction_communication_website_content,
     status,
     Year2016) %>% 
     rename(ComImpt=importance_communication_website_content, 
     ComSat = satisfaction_communication_website_content,
     status = status,
     year = Year2016)


 GapAnalysis17July <- select(memSatJuly17, 
    importance_communication_website_content_JULY17,
    satisfaction_communication_website_content_JULY17, 
    role_primary_new_JULY17,Year2017_July) %>% 
    rename(ComImpt=importance_communication_website_content_JULY17, 
    ComSat = satisfaction_communication_website_content_JULY17,
    status = role_primary_new_JULY17,
    year = Year2017_July)


 GapAnalysis <- rbind(GapAnalysis17July,GapAnalysis16)
```

And got my new combined data set:

```
   ComImpt ComSat status year
1       4      2      1    1
2      NA     NA      1    1
3       4      5      5    1
4       3      3      5    1
5       6      6      5    1
6       5      5      1    1
```

I needed it in long form so converted it:

```
    GapAnalysis_LongForm <-  GapAnalysis %>%
    gather(key = Product,value = Score, ComSat, ComImpt)
```

And now have this:

```
    status  year Product Score
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
 1     1.    1. ComSat      2.
 2     5.    1. ComSat      5.
 3     5.    2. ComSat      3.
 4     1.    1. ComSat      5.
 5     1.    1. ComImpt     4.
 6     5.    1. ComSat      4.
```

I now need to recode ComSat and ComImpt to values ( 1 & 2) but am stumped. Recode and recode_factor are giving me errors. I'm trying to get output something like this:

```
    status  year Product Score
     <dbl> <dbl> <chr>   <dbl>
 1     1.    1. 1           2.
 2     5.    1. 1           5.
 3     5.    2. 1           3.
 4     1.    1. 1           5.
 5     1.    1. 2           4.
 6     5.    1. 1           4.
```

Any general points in the right direction?

I appreciate it!!!

Comment: you reference but never provide the code that is not working, nor the actual output/error; if you expect any relevant help, I suggest you make this question a little more [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example)

Comment: And remove the code that is not directly related to the issue, describe expected output.

Answer (score 3):

I *guess* you are having some problems because you are using `recode_factor` outside of `mutate`. When you are modifying columns of a data frame, make sure that you use `mutate` (in the context of `tidyverse`).

The following should work and do the same thing.

---

### With the base `factor` function

```
df %>%
  mutate(Product = factor(Product, levels = c("ComSat", "ComImpt"), labels = c(1L, 2L)))
```

---

### With `recode_factor` function

```
df %>%
  mutate(Product = recode_factor(Product, "ComSat" = 1L, "ComImpt" = 2L))
```

or

```
df3 <- df %>%
  mutate_at(vars(Product), ~recode_factor(.,"ComSat" = 1L, "ComImpt" = 2L))
```

Answer (score 0):

If  there are only 2 `Product` codes (`ComSat,ComImpt`) in your data.frame then simple `ifelse` will be easier to help.

You need to additional step in `dplyr` chain as: `mutate(Product = ifelse(Product=="ComSat", 1L, 2L))`

```
GapAnalysis_LongForm  <- GapAnalysis %>%
  gather(key = Product,value = Score, ComSat, ComImpt) %>%
  mutate(Product = ifelse(Product=="ComSat", 1L, 2L))

#    status year Product Score
# 1       1    1       1     2
# 2       1    1       1    NA
# 3       5    1       1     5
# 4       5    1       1     3
# 5       5    1       1     6
# 6       1    1       1     5
# 7       1    1       2     4
# 8       1    1       2    NA
# 9       5    1       2     4
# 10      5    1       2     3
# 11      5    1       2     6
# 12      1    1       2     5
```

Answer (score 0):

Modifying the mutate_at approach of @hpesoj626:

Scoped verbs (_if, _at, _all) have been superseded by the use of across() in an existing verb according to tidyverse (see [here](https://dplyr.tidyverse.org/reference/mutate_all.html) for more info).

The following code should work:

```
df3 <- df %>%
  mutate(across(Product), ~recode_factor(.,"ComSat" = 1L, "ComImpt" = 2L))
```